# Courier Tracking Software - GPS - iPhone

Tags: asp.net, iphone, gps

I am developing a delivery management system that aims to allow a dispatcher to monitor where their couriers are around the city and be able to send addresses to the couriers, which would give them directions, etc. I am developing the backend in ASP.Net/MSSQL and am looking for an iPhone app that might give me a head start with the GPS tracking stuff.

Anyone familiar with this and have some suggestions for decent software? It does not have to be free software.

Thanks!

Comment: checkout DataTap by AptoLink in the appstore. I can provide a customised version of it if its the kind of thing you need.

Comment: @Andiih - Cheers, I've downloaded it and will check it out.

Comment: I should say it was written to their spec - with no design budget :-) But the functionality may be what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Titanium by Appcelerator might be what you need.  Coming from an ASP.Net/javascript background it's pretty easy to transition into Titanium.  Combine the built in libraries for geolocation and web services and you could be reporting your courier's positions using a timer to a web service pretty easily.

Link: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Geolocation-module